# Gitlab selfhosted when still has an APACHE server running

Tags: apache, nginx, gitlab, lets-encrypt, gitlab-ce

i am a bit confused.

I successfully installed a GITLAB selfhosted on the PORT 8081 of nGINX

My : /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file contains :

```
external_url "http://gitlab.xxxxx.online:8081"
nginx['listen_port'] = 8081
```

Why Port : 8081 ? Cause i still has my webapp running with apache on PORT 80.

So on apache, i create in  : /etc/apache2/sites-availabe/gitlab.proxy.conf

```
<VirtualHost gitlab.get-skills.online:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ServerName gitlab.get-skills.online
  ProxyPass / http://gitlab.xxxxx.online:80/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://gitlab.xxxxx.online:80/
</VirtualHost>
```

it works very well... but without HTTPS ...

How can i use Let's encrypt in my case ? cause the official doc is not working.

Do you have some Ideas ? i am not an expert with admin. system.

Thank you !!

Comment: HTTPS for which app? Gitlab on nginx or your other app on Apache?

Comment: Hi adam.Gitlab is hosted on nginx. So i supposed i have to configuré it . But apache is using the port 443 for https.so i have to change port for https on ngnix